# DELETE all with ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, message-queue, sql-delete

I'm building a poor's man FIFO message queue based on tables and trying to implement a `receiveAll` operation where all messages currently in the queue would be retrieved.

To receive a single message, I do:

```
WITH receiveCte AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 body
    FROM MyQueue WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
    ORDER BY id
)
DELETE FROM receiveCte
OUTPUT deleted.body;
```

From what I understand, the `ORDER BY` clause is necessary to guarantee the delete order, even if `id` is an identity primary key with a clustered index.

Now, to perform the `receiveAll` operation I need to delete all rows `ORDER BY id` and obviously that doesn't work without a `TOP` clause.

Therefore, I was thinking of performing a `SELECT` of the rows not locked and lock these for the entire transaction, then go on with the `DELETE`, however it seems I can't find a way to lock the rows affected by the select for the entire transaction.

```
BEGIN TRAN
    DECLARE @msgCount int;

    SELECT @msgCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM MyQueue WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, READPAST);

    ...
COMMIT TRAN
```

If I execute the above except the `COMMIT TRAN` and then execute the following statement in another connection, it still returns all rows while I expected to return `0` because of `READPAST` and the fact that there's an ongoing transaction holding `UPDLOCK` on the rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MyQueue WITH (READPAST)
```

Obviously, I must be doing something wrong...

**EDIT #1:**

@king.code already gave the perfect answer in this case, however I found out what was going on.

It turns out that `COUNT(*)` seems to be ignoring the lock hints so it wasn't adequate for testing.

Also, it seems that you need an `XLOCK` to make sure that `READPAST` does it's job.

**EDIT #2:**

WARNING: `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT ... ORDER BY` doesn't work because SQL Server seems to disregard the ORDER BY clause in that case. However, it seems that we can trick the optimizer using a variable e.g. `SELECT TOP (@hundred) PERCENT`, but I'm not sure how reliable that is.

Comment: I know this sounds silly but why re-invent the wheel? There are SO many FIFO messaging systems out there that are free and are very much tried and tested. Might I suggest that this may not necessarily be the best way to achieve your results? If you are set in going this route, why not select the ids into a temp table which you can then join onto to get your message body and also join onto to delete?

Comment: @twoleggedhorse Unfortunately, I work in a very controlled environment and even though we're on Windows, the programming language that we use has no support for MSMQ and the inter-op with C++ wouldn't be easy.  We might have more time to invest in this eventually, but for now we just need something that works and that's why I went down this path. Yes, selecting the IDs to lock the rows was an idea I had, if I do not find anything else that's what I will be doing.

Comment: Using the proper lock hints with that approach, would I be certain that the entire table would never be locked? That would be a huge problem because there's a lot of concurrent queuing.

Comment: Why not use SQL Server Broker Queues for this?

Comment: You state "When using SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT, the ORDER BY clause is disregarded", this isn't strictly true as the plan that is used still returns the data in the correct sorted order, it just doesn't need to re-sort the data as the data is returned from the clustered index in sorted order, so that a sort on the clustered index would be redundant.

Comment: Please see the following article on elimination of SORT in query plan when querying via an index https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181154%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I tried this and it worked for me:

**EDIT **

Updated based upon this [technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx) which states:

**"If you have to use TOP to delete rows in a meaningful chronological order, you must use TOP together with ORDER BY in a subselect statement."**

**Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE MyQueue
(
    ID INT Identity Primary Key,
    Body VARCHAR(MAX)
)


INSERT INTO MyQueue 
VALUES ('Message 1'),
        ('Message 2'),
        ('Message 3'),
        ('Message 4'),
        ('Message 5'),
        ('Message 6'),
        ('Message 7'),
        ('Message 8'),
        ('Message 9'),
        ('Message 10'),
        ('Message 11')
```

In one query analyser window I performed this:

**Query session 1**

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
GO
Begin Tran

;WITH receiveCte AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 body
    FROM MyQueue WITH (READPAST)
    ORDER BY id
)
DELETE FROM receiveCte WITH (ROWLOCK)
OUTPUT deleted.body;

-- note no COMMIT
```

**Query Session 2**

```
--Second window
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
GO
BEGIN TRAN

   DELETE FROM MYQueue WITH (ROWLOCK)
   WHERE ID IN
    (
        SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT ID
        FROM MyQueue WITH (READPAST)
        ORDER BY Id
    )
    OUTPUT deleted.Body

-- Note again no COMMIT
```

and then in the third window:

**Query Session 3**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MyQueue WITH (READPAST)
```

which correctly returned a result of **0**

Comment: I've just tested this myself, nice clean solution

Comment: Like I said, `TOP 100 PERCENT` is unreliable since the `ORDER BY` will be disregarded. It might seem like it works, if the optimizer choose to use the clustered index for ordering, which is the same as `ORDER BY id`, but that's just a coincidence, unless you can prove that the clustered index will always be used.

Comment: Here's a link to SQLCAT team - how to perform a fast ordered delete: http://web.archive.org/web/20100212155407/http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlcat/archive/2009/05/21/fast-ordered-delete.aspx

Comment: @plalx see using TOP to LIMIT the number of rows deleted - particularly the comment "If you have to use TOP to delete rows in a meaningful chronological order, you must use TOP together with ORDER BY in a subselect statement." see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> From what I understand, the ORDER BY clause is necessary to guarantee the delete order, even if id is an identity primary key with a clustered index.

You're right.

> Now, to perform the receiveAll operation I need to delete all rows ORDER BY id and obviously that doesn't work without a TOP clause.

Remember that you can use `PERCENT` in `TOP`:

```
DECLARE @Hundred FLOAT = 100;
SELECT TOP (@Hundred) PERCENT body
FROM MyQueue WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
ORDER BY id;
```

**UPDATE:**

I've just made some test. And it looks like that if I `ORDER BY` the Clustered Index, I get the same execution plan with and without `TOP(100) PERCENT`.

If I `ORDER BY` another column I see the Sort operation in execution plan even if I place `TOP(100) PERCENT`. So it looks like it is not ignored.

Anyway, since the `@Hundred` variable and the `TOP` expression are `FLOAT`, you can try to set it to something like this `99.99999` and see what happens.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't work because SQL Server will disregard the `ORDER BY` clause when `TOP 100 PERCENT` is used.

Comment: However, I found out that using a variable will trick the optimizer e.g. `SELECT TOP(@hundred) PERCENT` works. I'm not sure how reliable that is however.

Comment: If your are ordering by the CLUSTERED INDEX than you will not see a SORT in the query plan as the CLUSTERED INDEX is already sorted.

Comment: @SteveFord The CLUSTERED INDEX do not guarantee the sort order without the presence of an `ORDER BY` clause, if that's what you mean. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx

Comment: @plalx No what I mean is that if you are ordering by the clustered index in the ORDER BY clause and the optimiser chooses to use that clustered index to satisfy the query then there is no need for a sort in the query plan as the data is already sorted by the clustered index. If the optimiser chooses a different index to read from then there will indeed be a sort.

Comment: @SteveFord waht if the Query Engine decides to parallelize the query? Unsorted data.

Comment: @king.code if you have an ORDER BY in the SELECT it will not be unordered, the question is how the query optimiser chooses to satisfy the requirement to order the data.

Comment: @king.code for example if you create a simple table with a clustered index and SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY clusteredIndexKey you will more than likely not see a SORT in the query plan because the optimiser chooses to scan the CLUSTERED INDEX which is already ordered by clusteredIndexKey

Comment: @SteveFord Yes, I understand that part, but can you be sure that the optimizer will always choose the same plan? If not then that is unreliable.

Comment: @plalx if that is your concern then maybe you should consider using an INDEX HINT such as FROM table WITH (INDEX = 0) to force using the clustered index

Answer (score 2):

From DB point of view there is no big sense in deleting rows in any particular order if you are going to delete them all. Simple DELETE without ordering is just fine. 
If you are going to process row-by-row from application side, then start serializable transaction, block entire table and process\delete row-by-row based on ID, no ordering required.

Comment: I do not want to block the entire table. That's the point of READPAST.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using Broker Queues:

```
USE MASTER
CREATE DATABASE SBTest
GO

ALTER DATABASE SBTest SET ENABLE_BROKER;
GO

USE SBTest 
GO

CREATE Message TYPE MyMessage
VALIDATION = NONE
GO

CREATE CONTRACT MyContract (MyMessage SENT BY INITIATOR)
GO

CREATE QUEUE MYSendQueue
GO

CREATE QUEUE MyReceiveQueue
GO

CREATE SERVICE MySendService
    ON QUEUE MySendQueue (MyContract)
GO

CREATE SERVICE MyReceiveService
    ON QUEUE MyReceiveQueue (MyContract)
GO

-- Send Messages 
DECLARE @MyDialog uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @MyMessage NVARCHAR(128)
BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @MyDialog
    FROM SERVICE MySendService
    TO SERVICE 'MyReceiveService'
    ON CONTRACT MyContract
    WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF

    -- Send messages on Dialog
    SET @MyMessage = N'My First Message';
    SEND ON CONVERSATION @MyDialog
    MESSAGE TYPE MyMessage (@MyMessage)
    SET @MyMessage = N'My Second Message';
    SEND ON CONVERSATION @MyDialog
    MESSAGE TYPE MyMessage (@MyMessage)
    SET @MyMessage = N'My Third Message';
    SEND ON CONVERSATION @MyDialog
    MESSAGE TYPE MyMessage (@MyMessage)
GO


-- View messages from Receive Queue
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), message_body) AS Message
FROM MyReceiveQueue
GO


-- Receive 1 message from Queue
RECEIVE TOP(1) CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), message_body) AS Message
FROM MyReceiveQueue
GO
-- Receive All messages from Receive Queue
RECEIVE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), message_body) AS Message
FROM MyReceiveQueue
GO
-- Clean Up
USE master
GO
DROP DATABASE SBTest
GO
```

Comment: Broker queues might be a better approach and I will look into them, but that's out of the question's scope. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I believe SQL Server is determining that the action within the transaction does not require it to lock the rows that are "in use". I attempted to lock the table with something more obvious:

```
OPEN TRANSACTION
UPDATE MyQueue SET body = body
```

But even with that, it would still return the rows with the READPAST hint. However, if I actually change the rows:

```
OPEN TRANSACTION
UPDATE MyQueue SET body = body + '.'
```

Only then would my SELECT statement with READPAST return 0 rows. Seems that MSSQL is intelligent enough to minimize the locks on your table!

I suggest that if you want to hide rows from a READPAST hint, add a new column that can actually be edited without the fear of changing important data, and then in the process that locks the rows, update that row with an actual data change:

```
ALTER TABLE MyQueue ADD LockRow bit DEFAULT(0)
...
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE MyQueue SET LockRow = 1
```

If you do the above, your READPAST query should return 0 rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply need to delete all of the records as of now without blocking inserts and deletes that happen concurrently, you should simply issue this command:

```
DELETE FROM MyQueue WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
OUTPUT deleted.id, deleted.body;
```

This won't block neither inserts into MyQueue table, nor executions of the same statement concurrently. Concurrent executions will only pick up the records that were inserted after the previous `DELETE` transaction start time. Similarly, there is no need to do any `ORDER BY`, since the subject of deletion will be **all** records that existed in the table at the transaction start time.

Also I must mention that I strongly recommend not using the `ROWLOCK` hint, and let the SQL server decide which lock level to use for the top efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried issuing a HOLDLOCK hint, when selecting the rows? This should ensure that no other query can select the rows, until after the transaction is finished:

```
BEGIN TRAN
    DECLARE @msgCount int;

    SELECT @msgCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM MyQueue WITH (HOLDLOCK, ROWLOCK, READPAST);

    ...
COMMIT TRAN
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN Output documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx):

> There is no guarantee that the order in which the changes are applied
> to the table and the order in which the rows are inserted into the
> output table or table variable will correspond.

You can however insert the results of `OUTPUT` into a table variable, and then select back the results while keeping them ordered. Please note that using `rowlock` will require more resources if there are many records in the queue.

```
DECLARE @processQueue 
TABLE 
(     id int NOT NULL
    , body nvarchar(max) /*<- set to appropriate data type!*/
);

DELETE q
OUTPUT deleted.id, deleted.body 
INTO @processQueue(id, body)
FROM MyQueue q WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
;

SELECT body
FROM @processQueue q
ORDER BY q.id --ensure output ordering here.
;
```

Also since you have mentioned you do not want table locks, you can disable lock escalation on the `MyQueue` table.

```
--Disable lock escalation, to ensure that locks do get escalated to table locks.
ALTER TABLE MyQueue SET ( LOCK_ESCALATION = DISABLE );
go
```

Comment: Hum, that is an interesting fact I did not know, so basically using an `ORDER BY` with an `OUTPUT` clause is futile regarding the order in which results will be returned. However, in my case I'll still need an `ORDER BY` in the delete statement, since I'll also have to dequeue an arbitrary number of consecutive messages. Even if the `ORDER BY` gets disregarded with `TOP (100) PERCENT`, it changes nothing for the delete and since the OUTPUT order is not guaranteed then I'll still need to put another mechanism in place to ensure the ordering.

Comment: I've been trying a few things and I guess the table variable cannot be avoided? I haven't found any way to `SELECT` directly from an `OUTPUT` clause. Also, thanks for the `LOCK_ESCALATION` info, I guess that's the only way to prevent table locks since lock hints such as `ROWLOCK` are just hints after all.

Comment: From everything I have tried in the past, inserting the results into a table variable or temp table is the only way to ensure the results of an `output` clause are ordered. You may get the ordered results in testing when not using table variable, but that order could change at any time in the future. Another option is to have a column dedicated to queue processing in your `MyQueue` table and use a `UPDATE` with `rowlock, updlock, readpast` hints to set this column (maybe set to a GUID value to represent the current "de-queue set"), then `select` and then `delete` based on that column value.